What happens if you use sudo as root?
What happens if you use sudo as root? I use root by default and many tutorials have sudo and am wondering if there could be any adverse side effects from copying and pasting in sudo apt install remmina, for example. I know sudo as root is mainly redundant. I am mainly wondering because I don't want to take the time to remove sudo before copying and pasting and running as root.
Are there any side effects if you run sudo as root? Or are all three of these the same--running sudo as normal user, running as root, and running sudo as root?
I have done research with Perplexity AI Pro. I am using Kali Linux mainly. I understand that sudo runs as root. My question is not about how sudo works, except how sudo interacts with root when root runs sudo. I understand what sudo does.
In anticipation of the counterargument that I should not sign into Kali as root, my risk appetite is I want the gain of not having to sudo. Sometimes you run a command and it requires sudo and you have to run it again. Also, you end up typing in your password a lot with sudo so I operate as root by default.
I'm particularly interested in if there's some subtle obscure difference between root and root with sudo.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Running what? On what system(s)? What research have you done regarding this? Running as root has been widely discouraged for a LONG TIME (tm) and sudo has been considered the better option for even longer.

Does this answer your question? Difference between deleting folders using sudo or as root

No, this does not answer my question because I not deleting items.

It describes a difference in behavior between the two.

I'm the author of (so far) the only answer to the alleged duplicate. The issue there is just one specific aspect of "sudo vs root". While my answer answers that question (i.e. I still think the answer is a good answer there), it is not an exhaustive answer to the current question. In other words: definitely I would not post that answer here, I don't think the current question duplicates the linked one.

The default sudo user is root, so if you sudo a command as root, you run the command as root.

Check your sudo manual. Looking at the sudo manual at man.cx:

sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy.


-u user, --user=user
Run the command as a user other than the default target user (usually root).

It has more information about the authentication strategies, which are likely irrelevant, given that as root you have rights to use sudo.
Given that you are root, I assume your system uses root as the superuser. As you can see from the docs ("usually root") that may not always be the case.
Given that sudo can be used to execute commands as other users, for those commands keeping the sudo with parameters would even be necessary to execute them under that user.
So effectively, you will likely (not definitely because it depends on the system setup/OS configuration) run commands as the same root user, unless a user parameter is specified, where you would expect that other user anyway.
